# Perl Human Readable time with miliseconds to EPOCH

Tags: perl, epoch

I'm parsing SIP messages and we need to include milliseconds in the human readable part (i.e 2011/09/08 00:10:17.997) we need to convert them to Epoch time using Perl, I have found bunch of examples using from Human Readable to Epoch, but not including milliseconds, is this possible? I have found [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) in CPAN but im having a problem installing it. so looking for other options:
Example

```
$epoch = convert(2011/09/08 00:10:17.997)
print $epoch
```

and prints: 1315183552

Comment: Why don't you ask about the errors you're getting installing the `DateTime` module?

Comment: correct should be is 1315433417

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix whatever problem it is with your system that is preventing you from installing a module.

Barring that, Epoch time only has second resolution. Strip off the milliseconds and convert using [Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) (You'll need to parse your SIP message yourself)

```
$timestamp = "2011/09/08 00:10:17.997";
$timestamp =~ /(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;

# ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year);
$epoch = timelocal($6, $5, $4, $3, $2 - 1, $1 - 1900);
```

If it's *really* important, round the second using the milliseconds.

Comment: Time::HiRes::time includes milliseconds after the decimal as does DateTime::hires_epoc
 
perl -MTime::HiRes=time -e 'print time' # 1315549005.29001

Comment: Which ... isn't *epoch time*.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty if you are under linux:

```
$epoch = `date -d "2011/09/08 00:10:17.997" +%s`; print $epoch;
```

Comment: Ok managed to fix the  DateTime (Running MAC) will try suggestions