# convert a server timestamp to an epoch in variable

Tags: bash

`#!/bin/bash`

`ctime=`date +%s 
`# returns    1618634997   to $ctime`

`stime=$(wget --server-response --spider http://www.server.org/news_32.mp3 2>&1 | grep -i Last-Modified)`

`# returns : Last-Modified: Sat, 17 Apr 2021 04:49:57 GMT`
 `# into the variable $stime`

I need to convert `$stime` to epoch time, put it in `$etime` to compare them, and decide to download file, or not.

Need some code to manipulate the string.

to do date comparison

```
diff=$(( (ctime - eftime) / 86400 ))
echo $diff
```

Returns difference in days.

my solution, found after many attempts to break up the original string

`stime=$(wget --server-response --spider http://server.org.au/local.mp3 2>&1 | grep -i Last-Modified)`

`a=$stime`

`a=${a/*,/} ; a=${a/\ GMT/} ; dmt=${a/2021 /} ; dm=${a/2021*/} ; tm=${dmt/????????/} ; dd=${dm%?????*} ; mmm=${dm#*????}`

`fst="${mmm}${dd} ${tm}"`

`epoch=$(date -d "${fst}" +"%s")`

`echo "server file time = $fst"`

`ftime=$epoch`

`ctime=`date +%s``

`diff=$(( (ctime - ftime) / 86400 ))`

`echo "age "$diff" days"`

`exit`

very embarrassing , i know  :)
thanks for the answers , very new to this site ,now to try the easy ways.

Comment: If you're using GNU coreutils, you can use date(1)'s `-d` option, but that may pose portability issues for your use case. Is that on option for you?

Comment: If not, Perl has a human-readable date parser in its standard library; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357423/perl-human-readable-time-with-miliseconds-to-epoch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 eftime=$(date -d "$(wget --server-response --spider http://www.server.org/news_32.mp3 2>&1 | awk -F: '/Last-Modified/ { print $2 }')" +%s)
 diff=$(( (ctime - eftime) / 86400 ))
 echo $diff
```

Explanation:

```
 wget --server-response --spider http://www.server.org/news_32.mp3 2>&1 | awk -F: '/Last-Modified/ { print $2 }'
```

Take the output of the wget and then search a line with "Last-Modified" and print the second ":" delimited field. Use this as a date descriptor and use +%s to print in epoch format.

Comment: much better than the way I finally got the same result, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can use date for both.
Get epoch seconds and convert it back to normal date with...

```
date --date="@$(date +%s)"
```

If you like Lua then you can do...

```
-- get epoch seconds
>os.time()
1619002966
-- Convert it to a date
>os.date(_,os.time())
Wed Apr 21 13:03:11 2021
```